# Simple and common calculation in QFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory

It’s common that for simplicity for some calculation for a scalar field people substitute $(\nabla\phi)^2$ with $\phi \left(-~\nabla^2\right)\phi$.

I know I am not getting it right, $$(\nabla\phi)^2= (\partial_i\phi)(\partial^i\phi)+\phi \partial_i \partial^i \phi,$$ what’s the right expression or derivation to get that?

Comment: The right formula is $(\nabla\phi)^2= \partial_i(\phi\partial^i\phi) - \phi \partial_i \partial^i \phi$. You see that the difference of the  two relevant terms you mention is a boundary term. When dealing with integrated objects these boundary terms are neglected (if possible)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to be clear, 
$$(\nabla \phi)^2=(\nabla \phi)_i (\nabla \phi)^i =(\partial_i \phi) (\partial^i \phi) .$$

(I'm not sure what you meant by including that second term $\phi\partial_i \partial^i \phi$ in your equation. The way it's written, it's wrong). $i$ runs from $1$ to the spatial dimension of your theory $d$. By simply the product rule, we can rewrite this as

$$ (\nabla \phi)^2=\partial_i (\phi \partial^i \phi)-\phi\partial_i \partial^i \phi = \partial_i (\phi \partial^i \phi)-\phi\nabla^2 \phi.$$

The key here is that in field theory you are actually looking at the action $S$. We have:
$$S=\int \text{d}^dx \, (\nabla \phi)^2 = \int \text{d}^dx \left[ \partial_i (\phi \partial^i \phi)-\phi\nabla^2\phi \right] = 0 -\int \text{d}^dx \;\phi\nabla^2\phi.$$
The first term gives us zero because $\partial_i (\phi \partial^i \phi)$ are $d$ total derivative terms which when evaluated at the boundary each give zero as the field $\phi$ is assumed to vanish at infinity. Loosely speaking, this assumption is necessary in order for $S$ to converge (i.e. be finite).

Thus in conclusion, only under the sign of an integral can you interchange $(\nabla \phi)^2$ with $\phi(-\nabla^2) \phi$.

Answer (score -2):

HINT: Use partial integration (and Gaussian law with fields vanishing at boundary) for $\nabla$: $Y\nabla X = \nabla(YX)- X \nabla Y$ with $X,Y$ arbitrary complex numbers

Comment: Partial integration *under what integral* (the other answer does a good job at explaining that)? Since when can we differentiate "arbitary complex numbers"? What you wrote down there is the *product rule* for vector-valued functions.